# AutoCompleteTextView doesn't work when I enter first character

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

My AutoCompleteTextView doesn't work when I enter first character in textbox but starts showing dropdown when I enter second character. What could be the reason?

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:hint="@string/codehint"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hintgrey"
    android:dropDownWidth="fill_parent"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
/>
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You will need to set the `completionThreshold` property of your `autoCompleteView` to 1.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView 
    android:id="@+id/someID" 
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:completionThreshold="1" />
```

Or
for doing it dynamically through code use

```
mAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1)
```

### Happy Coding :)

Comment: @nobalG i am facing issue like this http://pastie.org/10678820# ,
problem is that there if i enter ap then those list items have ap those are not comes and display i want to show those items start from ap word or any inputted word

Comment: @amitsharma can you elaborate?

Comment: @nobalG please look at editted if i enter ap then those listitems start with ap those should display in list this is the issue

Comment: @amitsharma please show some code, or ask a question here at stackoverflow and send me a link of the question so that i can see it.

Comment: @amitsharma The component in which you are entering the input is an editText? right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100223/discussion-between-amitsharma-and-nobalg).

Comment: docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-1j5m7t669fnz8hbwlui371zeghoahhixz06eu57zmjmmwrgibl-6xk88fbhrbq38az6py8j82rd7 192.168.1.122:2377

Answer (score 2):

use i java code

```
autoComplete.setThreshold(1);
```

or
in xml

```
android:completionThreshold="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete;
     private MultiAutoCompleteTextView multiAutoComplete;
     private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the defined string-array 
        String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorList);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,colors);

        autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
        multiAutoComplete = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.multiAutoComplete);

        // set adapter for the auto complete fields
        autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
        multiAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

        // specify the minimum type of characters before drop-down list is shown
        autoComplete.setThreshold(1);
        multiAutoComplete.setThreshold(2);
        // comma to separate the different colors
        multiAutoComplete.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

        // when the user clicks an item of the drop-down list
        multiAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MultiAutoComplete: " +
                            "you add color "+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: i am geting this pastie.org/10678820#  , problem is that there if i enter ap then those list items have ap those are not comes and display i want to show those items start from ap word or any inputted word..

Answer (score 0):

If you want after clicking on `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`
Open the dialog

you must set the `completionThreshold` value to `0`
And `inputType` value to  `none`.

you can also increase the same field for the minimum number of characters.

**don't forget set** `inputType` to `text` or `number`

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:completionThreshold="0" <-- This line
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="none" />
```

**I hope hep**